# Java ProgressMonitor is not working

Tags: java, swing, swingworker, jprogressbar, progressmonitor

My code as below is not working, can anyone tell me why? Please also correct my code, I am very new to Java.  Besides that, I am searching for the "loading panel component", something like `ProgressMonitor` but maybe more attractive and which animates better. Please suggest me if anyone has used such things before.

```
public class Main extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Main frame = new Main();
                    frame.setVisible(true);

                    ProgressMonitor pm = new ProgressMonitor(frame, "Loading...", 
                            "waiting...",
                            0, 100000);

                    for (int i = 0 ; i < 100000 ; i ++){

                        pm.setProgress(i);
                        pm.setNote("Testing");
                        System.out.println(i);

                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Main() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @Mark Rotteveel already indicated, you are keeping the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) occupied. The tutorial on ['How to show progress bars/monitors'](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html) contains valuable information and code samples.

But basically it comes down to moving your calculations to a worker Thread (e.g. using a `SwingWorker`), and showing the `ProgressMonitor` on the EDT. It is up to the worker thread to indicate to the `ProgressMonitor` what progress has already been made.

And [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/ProgressMonitorDemoProject/src/components/ProgressMonitorDemo.java) is a direct link to the sample code of that tutorial which clearly shows how the work is done in the `SwingWorker` extension (the `Task` class in that example), and how the `ProgressMonitor` gets updated by adding a `PropertyChangeListener` to the `SwingWorker`, where the listener passes the progress to the `ProgressMonitor`.

I would also suggest to read the [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) tutorial which contains more information on how to handle `Thread`s in combination with Swing, and why you can't/shouldn't do heavy calculations on the EDT

Comment: Your answer is the best! Sweat, finally I managed to get it work after a long try.

Answer (score 5):

In Swing, the event-thread is what modifies and updates the GUI. You are keeping the event-thread busy with that for-loop and sleep, so it cannot update the GUI. All things you do on the event-thread should be short-lived. Everything else should be moved off the event-thread.

So you need to move that for-loop out of the event-thread.

Comment: Please, can show me how to do that? I have been googling for a day, the examples are very complicated... Please, a simple working code will do.

Comment: @GMsoF http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/AdemonstrationoftheProgressMonitortoolbar.htm & http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html

Answer (score 4):

**1.** Consider this as the rule of thumb, **UI work on UI thread, and Non-UI work on Non-UI thread**.

**2. Event Dispatcher Thread (EDT) is the UI thread** here, and so you should keep your **Non-UI process intensive work on a separate thread OUT of the EDT**.

**3.** You can do this in 2 ways.....

**i.** Create a **separate Thread** to do this.

**ii.** Use **SwingWorker** to synchronize the Non-UI and the UI thread.

**4.** Always keep the **main() method only for making the JFrame visible in the EDT**.

**eg:**

```
public static void main(String[] args){

       EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

         public void run(){

             myframe.setVisible(true);

            }
         }
      }
```

**Take a look at this site for the working example of SwingWorker:**

http://www.kodejava.org/examples/381.html